# query out all jsplumb connections before submit

Tags: javascript, jsplumb

I am using jsplumb to allow users to connect up a load of divs and I'd like to know if it is possible to query out the final state of all the connectors so that I can persist the state back on the server. The divs will all have id's that I'd like to get hold of when querying the connections.

Thanks for any help or advice.

Comment: see also this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17607438/can-we-export-a-jsplumb-flowchart-as-a-json-or-xml

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible to get all the connections and persist to database.

Try the `jsPlumb.getConnections()` function to get all connections.
From the function above you get for each connection an object with sourceId and targetId:s

Also take a look on the [demo page](http://jsplumb.org/jquery/draggableConnectorsDemo.html) -
it shows how to do it exactly.

Comment: HI @Rick I am unable to use jsPlumb.getConnections() in my case. I am using state machine. Is it different for state machine?