# Get the source and target of each connectors in jsplumb in jquery

Tags: svg, jsplumb

I am creating a flow chart in HTML using jsplumb to add connectors from one div to another.
Every time I create a connection from 1 div to another, my jquery code creates a svg for he connector.

I want to create a xml of the flowchart so that I can keep the flow of the diagram for this 
I need to find the source and target of a given svg connector(jsplumb connector).

basically I wanna store the flowchart in a xml format with the source and destination in the perfect place.

Can anyone help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get source and target using this method when you create a connection

```
jsPlumb.bind("jsPlumbConnection", function (conn) {
     var source = conn.source;
     var target = conn.target;               
});
```

Comment: thank you. That helped me alot to get the source n target once the connection is done.

Comment: Pleasure to hear that. Can you mark this as correct answer if it is

Answer (score 1):

to create xml of flowchart I guess answer for following question will help you. 
[Can we export a JsPlumb flowchart as a JSON or XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17607438/can-we-export-a-jsplumb-flowchart-as-a-json-or-xml/17626520#17626520)

Well I know I must give this link in comment but I am not allowed to comment yet as I don't have sufficient reputation. All the best :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use `jsPlumb.getConnections()` function to get all connections. Each connection has sourceId and targetId. [query out all jsplumb connections before submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9709694/query-out-all-jsplumb-connections-before-submit)

Comment: Once I create the flowchart i want to create a xml of the flow chart. Are there any easy ways to do that.

Comment: You will get this connections as JavaScript objects. By IDs or whatever you can get your connected divs and also extract only important information from them. Then you can serialize them to the xml format using this [link](http://www.onegeek.com.au/projects/javascript-serialization) or write your own function of creation xml code.

Comment: Use jsPlumb.getAllConnections() to get all current connections :)