# Can we export a JsPlumb flowchart as a JSON or XML?

Tags: xml, json, jsplumb

I have created a JSPlumb Flowchart. Now, I want to export this flowchart into its corresponding JSON or XML script to save and perform various operations. What is more compatible ? Either of them is perfectly fine. Please enlighten me on this. The JsPlumb code that I developed (with the help of various sites) is as given below.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example</title>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="Jquery\jq.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="Jquery\jq-ui.min.js"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jsPlumb-master\build\demo\js\jquery.jsPlumb-1.4.1-all-min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div  id="main">
    <div id="block1" class="node">node 0</div>
    <div id="block2" class="node">node 1</div>
    <div id="block3" class="node">node 2</div>
    <div id="block4" class="node">node 3</div>  
</div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

                var targetOption = {anchor:"TopCenter",
                                                    maxConnections:-1,
                                                    isSource:false,
                                                    isTarget:true,
                                                    endpoint:["Dot", {radius:8}],
                                                    paintStyle:{fillStyle:"#66FF00"},
                                                        setDragAllowedWhenFull:true}

                var sourceOption = {anchor:"BottomCenter",
                                                        maxConnections:-1,
                                                    isSource:true,
                                                    isTarget:false,
                                                    endpoint:["Dot", {radius:8}],
                                                    paintStyle:{fillStyle:"#FFEF00"},
                                                        setDragAllowedWhenFull:true}


                       jsPlumb.bind("ready", function() {

                        jsPlumb.addEndpoint('block1', targetOption);
                        jsPlumb.addEndpoint('block1', sourceOption);

                        jsPlumb.addEndpoint('block2', targetOption);
                        jsPlumb.addEndpoint('block2', sourceOption);

                        jsPlumb.addEndpoint('block3', targetOption);
                        jsPlumb.addEndpoint('block3', sourceOption);

                        jsPlumb.addEndpoint('block4', targetOption);
                        jsPlumb.addEndpoint('block4', sourceOption);

                        jsPlumb.draggable('block1');
                        jsPlumb.draggable('block2');
                        jsPlumb.draggable('block3');
                        jsPlumb.draggable('block4');                        
                });

     </script>

    <style type="text/css">
        .node {
    border:1px solid black;
    position:absolute;
    width:5em;
    height:5em;
    padding: 0.5em;
    z-index:1;
    border-radius:0.5em;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 19px #aaa;
    background: white;
    }

    #node0 { top:10em; left:22em;}
    #node1 { top:15em; left:32em;}

    </style>



</body>
</html>
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To export jsPlumb flowchart to JSON / XML firstly you would need to collect information about flowchart elements, then serialize it.

### Enumerating Blocks

To get information about blocks you can use plain jQuery:

```
var blocks = []
$("#main .node").each(function (idx, elem) {
    var $elem = $(elem);
    blocks.push({
        blockId: $elem.attr('id'),
        positionX: parseInt($elem.css("left"), 10),
        positionY: parseInt($elem.css("top"), 10)
    });
});
```

### Enumerating Connections

To get information about connections between elements you can use [jsPlumb API](http://jsplumbtoolkit.com/apidocs/jsPlumbInstance.html#getConnections), particularly "jsPlumb.getConnections()" method:

```
var connections = [];
$.each(jsPlumb.getConnections(), function (idx, connection) {
    connections.push({
        connectionId: connection.id,
        pageSourceId: connection.sourceId,
        pageTargetId: connection.targetId
    });
});
```

### Serializing to JSON

Once you collected all flowchart data you can serialize it to JSON:

```
var serializedData = JSON.stringify(blocks);
```

Comment: Thank u so much for the detailed explanation. I will perform this and let you know.

Comment: I am unable to get connections. I am using Jsplumb statemachine. I can serialize boxes but the connections object is null. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

We can use GetAllConnections instead of getConnection.

```
var connections = [];
function GetConn() {      
//connections = jsPlumb.getAllConnections();

$.each(jsPlumb.getAllConnections(), function (idx, connection) {
connections.push({
connectionId: connection.id,
pageSourceId: connection.sourceId,
pageTargetId: connection.targetId,
sourceText: connection.source.innerText,
targetText: connection.target.innerText,
});
});    
}
```