# How to get the sources and targets in JsPlumb

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jsplumb

I want to save my workFlow and then load it, For this I have to save all the sources and targets for all connections. Can anyone tell me how can I get all sources and targets against one node.

Answer (score 2):

Thankx buddy but I found a link that is very simple in syntax wise. Also that worked for me.
I'm going to share this for future references...

[Can we export a JsPlumb flowchart as a JSON or XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17607438/can-we-export-a-jsplumb-flowchart-as-a-json-or-xml)

Comment: bahi yeh to app nay mara hi copy ki ha :D :D :D

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to get all the connections first and then save each connection source and target id in an array. While restoring first you need to create DOM elements with same id's and then use the array to restore connections:

```
var con=jsPlumb.getAllConnections();
var list=[];
for(var i=0;i<con.length;i++)
{
     list[i]=new Array(2);
     list[i][0]=con[i].sourceId;
     list[i][1]=con[i].targetId;
}
```

For connecting elements based on id's make use of syntax:

```
jsPlumb.connect({source:list[1][0], target:list[1][1]});
```