# Getconnection() not working for state machine

Tags: javascript, jquery, state-machine, jsplumb

I am using [jsPlumb statemachine](http://www.jsplumb.org/demo/statemachine/dom.html). I would like to save and load my chart later. I googled and found that I would have to do it using json Object. I tried few examples [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17626520/1650891). I am able to get the positions of each of the box but I cannot get connections. All the examples I saw uses `jsPlumb.getConnections()` but for me it isn't working. I have added these connections and boxes dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are modifying example code you need to make 'instance' variable global and then call getConnections() method on it.

```
instance = jsPlumb.getInstance({
        Endpoint: ["Dot", {radius: 1}],
        HoverPaintStyle: {strokeStyle: "#1e8151", lineWidth: 1},
        ConnectionOverlays: [
            ["Arrow", {
                    location: 1,
                    id: "arrow",
                    length: 10,
                    width: 15,
                    foldback: 1
                }],
            ["Label", {label: "FOO", id: "label", cssClass: "aLabel"}]
        ],
        Container: "statemachine"
    });

 //...

instance.getConnections()
```